# How to ask correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I made up the sentence:

> I proclaimed myself king.

How to form correct questions?

> 1. Who proclaimed myself king?
> 2. Who did I proclaim myself?
> 3. Who did I proclaim king?

Please, correct my sentences.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Who proclaimed *me* king?

"*Myself*" is used when the subject *and* the object are both you.  Because you are *asking* "who" here, you *don't know* who the subject is.  Thus, you can't use "myself".

> 2. *What* did I proclaim myself?

*King* is a title here, and so it is a "what".  For comparison, *King James* is a "who".

---

Your third question is fine.  You could answer it with your given sentence, or simply "Myself."

Comment: "I proclaimed myself King James". The question would be "who did I proclaim myself?", right?

Comment: Not right, but I understand why it is confusing.  A name is a "what".  The person it names is a "who".  I'm not sure this will help, but consider this: you can write the words "an apple", but you cannot write an apple.  A word is not the thing it refers to; it is just the name for it.  But the mistake of using "who" there isn't confusing; it just indicates English might not be your first language.

Comment: "What did I proclaim myself?" is correct for all cases, no matter what word follows "I proclaimed myself ...", right?